# I got this error when i try to run the sqlite database by using python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I got this error when i run the db:

```sh
UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
```

it says that the problem is something here:

```py
def init_app(self, app):
    """This callback can be used to initialize an application for the
    use with this database setup.  Never use a database in the context
    of an application not initialized that way or connections will
    leak.
    """
    if (
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' not in app.config and
        'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' not in app.config
    ):
        warnings.warn(
            'Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. '
            'Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".'
        )
```

Comment: You should show YOUR code, not the code of the API cause that's most probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

Until we see the code that is causing the error I cannot for sure say whether this is the right answer, and I will update my answer if it is wrong, however that issue tends to arise when you call `init_app()` before the app is configured, when it tries to find it, it is blank as you didn't configure it so it resorts to the default `sqlite:///:memory:`

But please update your post to include your code, that way people will be able to assist, instead of showing the code of the import